# Add 'duplicate file' to Gedit file browser panel right-click menu?

Tags: gedit

In TextMate and other IDE's like Netbeans, there is a right-click option to duplicate a file. Is it possible to add this feature in Gedit file-browser panel on right click?

Currently, I can create new files, folders, delete existing one's, rename, even 'open terminal here'. How come we don't have the 'duplicate file' option?

---

From using External tools, I have come up with this script:

**NOTE:** I'm not that much of a python programmer :-)

```
#!/bin/sh

DocDir=$GEDIT_CURRENT_DOCUMENT_DIR #document directory
DocNm=$GEDIT_CURRENT_DOCUMENT_NAME #document name

NNM=$DocNm'_copy' #append _copy to document name
cp "$DocRir/$DocNm" "$DocDir/$NNM" #duplicate
```

So far, it's duplicating the file alright though there are some problems I have encountered:

1. `index.php` is being renamed to `index.php_copy` => it should be `index_copy.php`
2. `init.jquery.js` should be `init_copy.jquery.js`

The preferrable solution would be to extract the first part of the document name, append '_copy' and then join it with the last part of the name (the exension).

Can you improve the script or even create a better one?

Comment: I will try my example later today :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a solution that should work with the [ExternalTools plugin](https://wiki.gnome.org/action/show/Apps/Gedit/Plugins/ExternalTools?action=show&redirect=Gedit%2FPlugins%2FExternalTools) recommended by @Rinzwind:

```bsh
#!/bin/bash

FILE="$GEDIT_CURRENT_DOCUMENT_PATH"

FILENAME="${FILE##*/}"
EXTENSION_PRE="${FILENAME#*.}"
BASENAME="${FILENAME%%.*}"
DIRNAME="${FILE%/*}"

if [[ "$FILENAME" = "$EXTENSION_PRE" ]] # handle files without extension
  then
      EXTENSION=""
  else
      EXTENSION=".$EXTENSION_PRE"
fi

cp -v "$FILE" "$DIRNAME/${BASENAME}_copy$EXTENSION"
```

I tested it for files without extension (e.g. `Untitled Document`), with a single extension (e.g. `Untitled Document.txt`) and composite extensions (e.g. `Untitled Document.text.txt`).

Here's how I set it up with gEdit's external tools (this setup will show the (verbose) output of cp in the bottom pane):

[image]

---

**Edit**

Here's a step-by-step explanation of what the code does:

```bsh
#!/bin/bash
#  Note: we are using /bin/bash and not /bin/sh
#  /bin/sh is the DASH shell, /bin/bash the BASH shell
#
#  We need BASH to perform the string manipulations on
#  the file path.
#
#  More information on the differences may be found here:
#  - http://stackoverflow.com/a/8960728/1708932
#  - https://wiki.ubuntu.com/DashAsBinSh

FILE="$GEDIT_CURRENT_DOCUMENT_PATH" # assign the full file path provided
                                    # by gedit to a shorter variable

# What follows are a number of bash string manipulations.
# These are very well documented in the following article:
# - http://linuxgazette.net/issue18/bash.html

# 1.) remove everything preceding (and including) the last slash
#     in the file path  to get the file name with its extension
#     (e.g. /home/test/file.tar.gz → file.tar.gz)
FILENAME="${FILE##*/}"

# 2.) remove everything in the file name before (and including)
#     the first dot to get the extension
#     (e.g. file.tar.gz → tar.gz)
EXTENSION_PRE="${FILENAME#*.}"

# 3.) remove everything in the file name after (and including) 
#     the first dot to get the basename
#     (e.g. file.tar.gz → file)
BASENAME="${FILENAME%%.*}"

# 4.) remove everything after (and including) the last slash
#     in the file pathto get the directory path
#     (e.g. /home/test/file.tar.gz → /home/test)
DIRNAME="${FILE%/*}"


# If there's no extension in the filename the second string manipulation
# will simply print the filename. That's why we check if $FILENAME and
# $EXTENSION_PRE are identical and only assign EXTENSION to a value if
# they aren't.

if [[ "$FILENAME" = "$EXTENSION_PRE" ]]
  then
      EXTENSION=""
  else
      EXTENSION=".$EXTENSION_PRE"
fi

# in the last step we compose the new filename based on the string 
# manipulation we did before and pass it to cp
cp - v "$FILE" "$DIRNAME/${BASENAME}_copy$EXTENSION"
```